# awk to count and print header row of file

Tags: awk

I am using a combination of `head` and `awk` to count the number of fields in the header row of the `tab-delimited` `file`. The below seems very close but I also want to print the header names in `file` on a newline.  There probably is a better way but hopefully its a start.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
Index   Chr Start   End Ref ALT
```

**awk** with current output

```
head -n 1 file | awk -F'\t' '{print NF " fields detected in file"}'
6 fields detected in file
```

**desired output**

```
6 fields detected in file
Index   Chr Start   End Ref ALT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
$ awk ' {print NF " fields detected in file"} END {print}' f
6 fields detected in file
Index   Chr Start   End Ref ALT
```

**OR**

```
$ awk ' {print NF " fields detected in file"RS $0;exit}' f
6 fields detected in file
Index   Chr Start   End Ref ALT
```

Comment: perhaps set the FS to tab in case some field names have space in them.

Comment: Thank you both very much :).

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR you really need some more coffee this morning! The first script will only work in some awks as it relies on undefined behavior per POSIX of `$0` being populated in the END section, should just use `print NF, "..."` instead of `printf NF " ...\n"`, doesn't need to specify `$0` in a print as that's the default. The second one has some of the same problem as the first plus you should never do `printf $0`, always `printf "%s", $0` instead as the former will fail cryptically when your input contains printf formatting characters, and don't hard-code "\n" use ORS for portability.

Comment: You're getting closer but that first command line simply will not work (it'll print the same output for every line of the input file rather then just once and then what it;ll print in the END is undefined) so you should get rid of it. Also in your second script your OUTPUTING text so you should be using the OUTPUT RS (ORS) not the input RS and why hard-code a space in a string rather than just `print NF, "..."`. Once you fix all of that your answer will look exactly like mine of course...

Answer (score 1):

if your file has is not just header but contains data as well

```
awk -F'\t' '{print NF " fields detected in file"; print; exit}' file
```

you don't need `head` statement.  However, you're just checking the header and a better QC script should check all record lengths.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'\t' '{print NF, "fields detected in file" ORS $0; exit}' file
```

Comment: No it won't. The fields are tab-separated - see the example in the  question where the OP specifically shows that using `-F'\t'` on the input file DOES output 6 as the number of fields.